# Colorbox and Drupal Views Ajax Pager

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, colorbox

I am working on a Drupal site where [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is being used for images, but it's been added manually, not via a module.

The problem occurs when Colorbox is being used for a photo-gallery generated with Views and paging is handled with AJAX. The first page works fine, but any additional pages do not fire the Colorbox pop-up.

It seems to me that Colorbox is not aware of the new elements, because they were not present in the DOM when the page was loaded. With that thought I attempted to bind the Colorbox $.colorbox.init() method to the paging event, but always returns the error:

"Undefined: $.colorbox.init()"

Here is what I added to Drupal's Views module to test this, upon Success status from the paging event (ajax_views.js line:132):

```
    success: function(response) {
                $.event.trigger('pagedContent');
```

Here is what I'm catching it with:

```
$(document).bind('pagedContent', function() {  
  $.colorbox.init(); });
```

I also tried just running the regular initialization again instead, with no results.

```
 $(document).bind('pagedContent', function() {  
  $('myselector').colorbox(); });
```

I'm sure I should approach this a little differently to follow drupal best practices, but this seems like it should work and I'm wondering why it does not. Am I way off track here, is the approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Drupal Behaviors, or JQuery live function, in order to attach events to elements that appear asynchronously.